# How to replace Ctrl+M character from spark dataset using regexp_replace()?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi have a Spark dataset with one of its column having a `Ctrl+M` char present in the column's data, as a result that record is getting split into two records, and data corruption.
Even though I have added the code for handling regex newline `\r\n`, but I am not sure if this same code will be able to handle Ctrl+M, i.e. `^M`:

```
filtered = filtered.selectExpr(convertListToSeq(colsList))
              .withColumn(newCol, functions.when(filtered.col(column).notEqual("null"), functions.regexp_replace(filtered.col(column), "[\r\n]", " ")));
```

Will the code `functions.regexp_replace(filtered.col(column), "<ascii for Ctrl+M>", " ");` work ? ..I don't know the ascii value of Ctrl+M.

Comment: have you tried this `functions.regexp_replace(filtered.col(column), "\\r$" , "")`

Comment: I just tried the same code `regexp_replace(filtered.col(column), "[\r\n]", " ")` and it is able to remove Ctrl+M. But I will try your suggession as well....to explore if my case can be resolved by more than just one way :)

Comment: yeah post further results here